# ASP.NET MVC 3 Charting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, charts

I'm new to this Charting thing, and the way I'm doing it is very inefficient so I figure there should be a better way.

Currently I have a Controller that creates a Model which pulls all the data from the database, and does lots of parsing and the like, then displays that all in a View, where the data is laid out in several tables.

Also in the View are a series of img that calls an action in the controller. That action generates a new instance of the Model and uses the data to create a chart image which it returns to the View.

Since I already have the required data in the View, how can I create the chart entirely from there? Or even better, create it in the Model and reference it in the View? It should be possible but my googling hasn't been fruitful.

Here's some code.

View

```
<% foreach (ProjectEnrollment projectEnrollment in Model.ProjectEnrollments) { %>
    <img src='/pts/reports/Chart?year=<%= Model.Year %>&projectID=<%= projectEnrollment.ProjectID %>' alt="Chart"/>
<% } %>
```

Controller

```
 public FileResult Chart(string year, int projectID)
 {
ProjectEnrollment projectEnrollment = new ProjectTargetVsActualModel(year).ProjectEnrollments.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProjectID == projectID);

if (projectEnrollment != null)
{
    Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<double>> data = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<double>>();
    data.Add("P", projectEnrollment.P.Select<int, double>(i => i).ToList());
    data.Add("Planned P", projectEnrollment.PlannedP.Select<int, double>(i => i).ToList());
    data.Add("S", projectEnrollment.S.Select<int, double>(i => i).ToList());
    data.Add("Planned S", projectEnrollment.PlannedS.Select<int, double>(i => i).ToList());
    ChartHelper ch = new ChartHelper();
    return ch.CreateChart(SeriesChartType.Line, 800, 300, null, projectEnrollment.Headers, data);
}

return null;
}
```

I know there's a lot of detail missing from those code snippets. But I hope it's enough to get the idea of how I'm currently doing things.

As you can see the current setup is quite inefficient. Is there a way I can do it with only one Model instance? Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Chart objects can use SaveImage to save into a MemoryStream. MemoryStreams can be output as byte[] with ToArray(). I do all that and store the byte[] in the Model.

In the View, the byte[] can be displayed as an image, like so.

```
<% var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(projectEnrollment.Chart);
var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64); %>
<img src="<%= imgSrc %>" alt="Chart"/>
```